# Evaluating RegEx patterns within a string

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following code:

```
userInput = "develop-feature-21"
entry = "develop-feature-**"
entry = entry.replace("**", ".*");
println (userInput ==~ "$entry") // ------> false
```

I basically want to replace `**` and add in a valid regular express `.*` to find all entries of `develop-feature`, but the problem I am having is evaluating a RegEx expression within a string.

`$entry` becomes `develop-feature-.*`, but how do I tell groovy to then evalulate `.*`?

Comment: You must have came to groovy from perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've seen this in old version of groovy. i have 2.5 and your code works for me.

you could try to use

```
println (userInput ==~ entry)
```

instead of

```
println (userInput ==~ "$entry")
```

```
userInput = "develop-feature-21"
entry = "develop-feature-**"
entry = entry.replace("**", ".*");
println (userInput ==~ entry) //----------> true
```